# Sequelize - order by in nested model not working for mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

There are 3 models in my database:

```
Section (1:m) Sub_Section (1:m) Questions
```

These 3 models have a field called `order`, and I want to use it to order my data.
However I am not able to use order by for this Association.

**Updated the code**

```
var SectionQuery = {
    include: [{
        model: sub_section,
        order: [['order', 'asc']],
        include: [{
            model: question,
            order: [['order', 'asc']],
        }]
    }]
};
return Section.findAll(tehsilQuery);
```

Comment: Incidentally, order is a reserved word in MySQL

Comment: @Strawberry how should I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it.

```
var SectionQuery = {
    include: [{
        model: sub_section,
        as:"sub_sections",
        include: [{
            model: question,
            as:"questions",
        }]
    }],
    order = [
          ["order", "asc"],
          ["sub_sections","order", "asc"],
          ["sub_sections","questions","order", "asc"],
    ]
};
return Section.findAll(SectionQuery);
```

Comment: Worked for me. In case someone else is looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var SectionQuery = {
        include: [{
            model: Section,
            as: "section",
            include: [{
                model: Sub_Section,
                as: "sub_section",
                include: [{
                    model: Questions,
                }]
            }]
        }],
        order: [
    [{model: Section, as: "section"}, "order", "asc"],
    [{model: Section, as: "section"}, {model: Sub_Section, as: "sub_section"}, "order", "asc"]
]
    };
    return Sections.findAll(tehsilQuery);
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: there are mistakes in code and I've corrected. Please help thanks